# Export AD members from specific AD groups

Tags: powershell

I want to retrieve the SamAccountName from a number of ~600 AD groups that end with a certain string.

For example:

```
AD Groups:
AAA-BBB-XXX
CCC-DDD-XXX
EEE-FFF-XXX
```

Now I want to get the SamAccountName of all AD groups that end with XXX but also, with a relation between SamAccountName and AD-group so that I know to which AD-group they belong. So:

```
SamAccountName | AD GROUP
------------------------------
Bernie.Sanders | AAA-BBB-XXX
Donald.Trump  | AAA-BBB-XXX
Barack.Obama  | AAA-BBB-XXX
Joe.Biden     | CCC-DDD-XXX
```

I have managed exporting all XXX AD-groups to .csv with -like and -filter operator.
I have managed exporting all SamAccountName using Get-ADGroupMember and -identity operator.

But, I'm not able (yet) to create the above list as I'm a PS newbie. I'm looking for some 'where' statement and require some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to combine the "AD Group Members" with the "AD Group Name". For filtering the groups that matches your condition, in this case, *ending with XXX* you can use the `-LDAPFilter` or `-Filter` from [`Get-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlet.

```
$filter = "(samAccountName=*XXX)" # => Ends with XXX

$result = foreach($group in Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $filter)
{
   # Here all groups ending with XXX are being enumerated

   Get-ADGroupMember $group | Select-Object @{
      Name = 'ADGroup'
      Expression = { $group.samAccountName }
   }, samAccountName, ObjectClass
}

$result | Export-Csv ....
```

Note that, *AD Groups* can have members that are **not only users**, if you wanted to the group members where their class is "User" you could add `Where-Object` or `.Where()` method:

```
Get-ADGroupMember $group |
    Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' } |
    Select-Object ....
```

```
(Get-ADGroupMember $group).Where({
    $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'
}) | Select-Object ....
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It works. I didn't need to use the Where as I could delete those non-user entries in Excel. However, this part confused me: 
    
    $filter = "(samAccountName=*XXX)" 

Even though I got the desired results, it looks like the filter is put on samAccountName and not the AD-group itself.

Comment: @David my pleasure, happy to help. The LDAP filter there means _"filter all AD Groups where it's samAccountName ends with XXX"_ you could read it that way.

Comment: Hi ! Ok - So samAccountName can be both a user object (joe.biden) as well as the name of an AD-Group. Thanks

Comment: @David all AD Objects have the _sAMAccountName_ attribute afaik